# Fastest way to replace last occurrence of pattern in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

After some looking around at different questions about replacing the last word, I didn't find one that covered the **fastest way**. In my scenario I want to replace the last bit of a string after a period, or the last word and everything after.

To better explain, this method replaces the string exactly how I want it: (Edit: I changed the regex based on Avinash's response, still looking for a faster alternative as the regex replaceall is still slow)

```
return permission.replaceAll("\\w+(?:\\.\\*)?$", "*");
```

Example in -> out

```
test.test.test -> test.test.*
test.test.* -> test.*
```

While this works, I am looking for a faster way to achieve the same results. This method is called often and it has appeared at the top of my profiling cpu results.

Comment: Oh no, i answered your original question. Ok, if someone answer like, this is the faster way than `"\\w+(?:\\.\\*)?$"`, then you change your question to "i changed my regex based on this regex. I'm still looking for faster way" ? This is not the right behavior. Revert your edit. And wait for some more time. Someone may come with the solution fatser than mine.

Comment: Should you be reusing a compiled pattern instead? If the regex does not change then find the regex pattern and compile it and reuse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just posting this as an answer as it was inside of the comments of another answer:

Answer by Joop Eggen:

> Thanks for letting me know, One never knows. The regex way: replaceFirst of course; and not to forget for multiple replacements private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern,compile("\w+(?:\.\*)?$"); ... s = PATTERN.matcher(s).replaceFirst("*");

Evidence: http://ideone.com/vsObMZ Pattern proves to be the fastest method so far so this will be the accepted answer.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?:\\.\\*)?$");
return p.matcher(permission).replaceFirst("*");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static String lastWord(String s) {
    if (s.endsWith(".*")) {
        s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 2);
    }
    int pos = s.lastIndexOf('.') + 1;
    return s.substring(0, pos) + '*';
}
```

Regular expression is slow. You might use `Pattern.compile` to make a global Pattern for a speedup, but here it is simpler to not use regex.

Comment: This does not pass the two tests I posted above. When inputting test.test.* your code will output out the same thing when it should output test.*

Comment: Ok, so far this is the fastest method, I'll wait a few days before I accept an answer though.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, One never knows. The regex way: `replaceFirst` of course; and not to forget for multiple replacements `private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern,compile("\\w+(?:\\.\\*)?$"); ... s = PATTERN.matcher(s).replaceFirst("*");`

Comment: I just finally got back to this after forgetting about it. The comment you made on the regex way appears to be the fastest method. http://ideone.com/vsObMZ

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a alternation operator here. Put `\\.\\*` inside a non-capturing group after `\\w+` and make it as optional by adding `?` quantifier next to that group. Use capturing groups if necessary. That is, this replacement won't require a capturing group to capture characters which are to be referred later. These modifications must decrease the processing time.

```
string.replaceAll("\\w+(?:\\.\\*)?$", "*");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dW8mK5/6)

Comment: I did this, and it did not have a significant affect on the time it takes. It did lower, but not nearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.+\.(?=\w)).*
```

Try this.Replace by `$1*`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/dW8mK5/7